# ListView not found in ViewPager View inflater implementation

Tags: android

I am inflating Views (not fragments) in my viewpager implementation.
My main class extends Activity.

Page 1 of the viewpager inflates a view made up of textviews. Page 2 inflates an achartengine piechart. All works well.

Page 3 is supposed to inflate a listview with a custom adapter. However, as I've only extended Activity, setListAdapter isn't available.

If I change the main class to extend ListActivity, then the entire activity fails on load because it can't find the android.R.id.list view (because it hasn't been inflated yet)

This is the instantiate code I am using

```
public class SummaryPagerAdapteri extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //find and inflate the view
            resId = R.layout.recordsummary_one;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    //do stuff
            break;
        case 1:
    //find and inflate the view
            resId = R.layout.recordsummary_two;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            Context ctx = view.getContext();
            //do stuff  
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.recordsummary_three;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            Context tctx = view.getContext();
            if(pdn != null){
            adapter = new SummaryNotesAdapter(tctx,pdn);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            }                  
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.recordsummary_four;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    //ToDo
            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.recordsummary_five;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    //ToDo
            break;
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can use setListAdapter(adapter) without extending ListView, or how I can extend ListView without the activity failing when it can't find the uninflated view on first load?

Many thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate a regular ListView for page 3 and call [ListView.setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) to set the adapter. In your code this will either be:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or

```
view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks AdamK, works a charm. I used the second option. In using that, I had to change the listview id in the layout file from '@android:id/list' to '@+id/whatever_you_want'